# TSQL : Find combinations of rows within group without a cross joins

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to develop a T-SQL routine (SQL Server 2014), which will allow me to find all combinations of records within group.

Given the following data:

```
ID_COMBINATION | ID_POSITION | MULTIPLY_FACTOR
-----------------------------------------------    
       1       |        1    |        1
       1       |        1    |        2
       1       |        1    |        3
       1       |        2    |        1
       1       |        2    |        2
       1       |        2    |        3
```

I would like to calculate a combination of MULTIPLY_FACTOR for full set of ID_POSITIONS for a given ID_COMBINATION

The result should be:

```
1 | 1 | 1
1 | 2 | 1
1 | 1 | 1
1 | 2 | 2
1 | 1 | 1
1 | 2 | 3
...
1 | 1 | 3
1 | 2 | 3
```

For the moment I prefer to have a closed routine definition (over using dynamic SQL to generate multi cross joins code at run-time, depending on the number of unique ID_POSITIONS within a group)

Thank you very much for your help!

**EDIT:**

The following TSQL code calculates combinations of unique ID_POSITION for a given ID_COMBINATION 1:

```
declare @Samples as Table ( Id_Combination Int, Id_Position Int, Multiply_Factor Int );
INSERT INTO @Samples (Id_Combination, Id_Position, Multiply_Factor)
    VALUES (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3)
    , (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3)

SELECT
    S1.Id_Combination
    ,S1.Id_Position AS s1_idpos
    ,S1.Multiply_Factor AS s1_mufac
    ,S2.Id_Position AS s2_idpos
    ,S2.Multiply_Factor AS s2_mufac
FROM @Samples AS S1
INNER JOIN @Samples AS S2
    ON s1.Id_Combination = s2.Id_Combination
    AND s1.Id_Position < s2.Id_Position
```

However, if I add a new ID_POSITION key with respective MULTPLY_FACTOR values I will have to modify join conditions and select statement to cover new scenarios, like:

```
declare @Samples as Table ( Id_Combination Int, Id_Position Int, Multiply_Factor Int );
INSERT INTO @Samples (Id_Combination, Id_Position, Multiply_Factor)
    VALUES (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3)
    ,(1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3),
    ,(1, 3, 1), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 3);

    SELECT
        S1.Id_Combination
        ,S1.Id_Position AS s1_idpos
        ,S1.Multiply_Factor AS s1_mufac
        ,S2.Id_Position AS s2_idpos
        ,S2.Multiply_Factor AS s2_mufac
        ,S3.Id_Position AS s3_idpos
        ,S3.Multiply_Factor AS s3_mufac
    FROM @Samples AS S1
    INNER JOIN @Samples AS S2
        ON s1.Id_Combination = s2.Id_Combination
        AND s1.Id_Position < s2.Id_Position
    INNER JOIN @Samples AS S3
        ON s2.Id_Combination = s3.Id_Combination
        AND s2.Id_Position < s3.Id_Position
```

Getting back to my question general idea: how to write "generic" TSQL code here, which will cover all possible, future values from the ID_POSITION domain and present values vertically rather then adding new fields in SELECT clause.
For sure, some SUB_COMBINATION key will have to be introduced, to make those combinations distinct within each other inside a parent ID_COMBINATION...

Comment: Why are you opposed to using a cross join?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Because I cannot assume a size of ID_POSITION set at a design time. Given that, I cannot code this solution without using dynamic SQL. It's more about looking for an alternative for dynamic SQL here, rather than being opoped to CROSS JOINs.

Comment: If  I correct your new sample code and execute it I get a result that is quite unlike the sample result you've supplied, i.e. seven columns instead of three. I'm confused.

Comment: @HABO: My sample code coming from the question edit shows that using a generic solutions (JOINS) does not give me a result structured in a required way, i.e. ID_COMBINATION,ID_POSITION,MULTPLY_FACTOR.
PS. Can one who downvotes present some arguments behind his actions?

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't figure out your comment re: "a size of ID_POSITION", I'll just ask why it isn't this easy:

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Samples as Table ( Id_Combination Int, Id_Position Int, Multiply_Factor Int );
insert into @Samples ( Id_Combination, Id_Position, Multiply_Factor ) values
  ( 1, 1, 1 ), ( 1, 1, 2 ), ( 1, 1, 3 ), -- ( 1, 1, 4 ), -- Try me.
  ( 1, 2, 1 ), ( 1, 2, 2 ), ( 1, 2, 3 );
select * from @Samples;

-- Generate all possible combinations of all values.
select distinct S1.Id_Combination, S2.Id_Position, S3.Multiply_Factor
  from @Samples as S1 cross join @Samples as S2 cross join @Samples as S3
  order by Id_Combination, Id_Position, Multiply_Factor;
```

Note that if you uncomment the extra sample data row you will get *two* more result rows.

Comment: By saying "size of ID_POSITION" I mean that for each ID_COMBINATION number of unique ID_POSITION values will vary.